# Wordpress and JavaScript: trying to hide a button when the product has no sku

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hide, getelementsbyclassname

I have this situation with my Wordpress site where products with variations are hitting the DOM while missing some inner text on a certain element (which is the same behavior as a product without a sku), but when I console.log the element, the text is there.  Here is the code:

```
const makerBtn = document.getElementById("maker-button");
const sku = document.getElementsByClassName("sku");
    
const newLink = document.createElement("a");
newLink.innerText = "Buy at Maker's Site";
newLink.className += "fusion-button button-flat fusion-button-default-size button-custom button-3 fusion-button-default-span fusion-button-default-type";
newLink.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        newLink.target = "_blank";
        newLink.href = sku[0].innerHTML.toString();
});
        
makerBtn.appendChild(newLink);
```

I've added url's to some products in the sku and if they are there, then you click the button and you will be taken to a new site.  I've just been trying to find a way to hide the button if it doesn't have a sku, but if I add code like this:

```
if (sku[0].innerHTML === "") {
         newLink.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

It will work except the button is hidden for products that have variations too (they have a dropdown menu and you can choose between different colors, etc.) because the sku[0].innerHTML is hitting the DOM as an empty string even though I console log it and the url is there.

I can't figure out which property of these variable products I can add to a conditional so that these pages behave differently.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe you can try:

```
if (sku[0].innerHTML === "") {
    newLink.style.opacity= "0.0"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that sku[0].innerHTML === "" is true for the variable products on load.  I can't figure out why.  Plus I'm using Wordpress, so I can't add a breakpoint.  The console is lying to me... :(